# Should I include Modernizr in my MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modernizr

Now that I'm busy optimizing my application, I was wondering if should include Modernizr in my MVC project since we are in 2017 and the minimum version of our browser is IE 10 and latest Chrome.

Comment: This is really an opinion question. It depends *entirely* on your applications requirements and how it is architected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... Modernizr doesn't do anything on its own, you have to use its feature detection to change your code.... So if you do not plan to change your JS or CSS based on the flags it provides then No - there is no point in including it